# How to throttle use of a specific query to an LAMP based CMS

Tags: apache, drupal, lamp

Our Drupal CMS calendar crashes if too many users try to access at once.  Is there a way to throttle requests to the calendar to x number per minute etc?

Comment: so your users will be waiting? I guess it's better to improve your queries, database configuration or even heardware.

Comment: Have you spent any time trying to optimize Drupal at all?  There are some good links available in the Drupal documentation: http://drupal.org/node/326504

Comment: Clear question, how it is crashed, what show, how many users, server parameters, used caching tools etc...

Answer (score 0):

There is a module that will Throttle drupal. It is one of the Core modules, in fact I think its called Throttle.

It sounds like you need to employ the use of caching. Admin / Configuration / Performance -> Enable CSS/JSS aggregation. Download the Boost module to create static HTML files of the website to serve up to anonymous users. I don't know anything about your site, but if no one has to log in, Boost will help you big time.

This should alleviate/help your bottleneck. But we need to know more to provide better direction.